# Object parameter not accepting string

Tags: java

I have a method with following signature -

```
public void errorNew(final int a, final String key, final Object... params);
```

And I am trying to call it as -

```
errorNew(1, "a", "vb", "df");
```

But eclipse is showing me error -

```
The method errorNew(int, String, Object[]) in the type Logger is not applicable for the arguments (int, String, String, String)
```

Any idea about the reason?

When I try to build using maven, it shows following error -

```
 method errorNew in interface Logger cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: int,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[]
[ERROR] found: int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String
[ERROR] reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Compiles fine for me. http://ideone.com/c6KIaw

Comment: For me too. Please, provide more context.

Comment: strange...then why is eclipse showing error...

Comment: I dont think there is anything more... the case is so simple..

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and recompiling everything?

Comment: Maybe you got another override from another class/etc.

Comment: I cleaned and tried to build using maven. Still giving problems. I have included the maven error in question now.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA / Eclipse do "go to declaration" and see if it go to your method.

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: Cant share code :( but I have only one method in whole project with such ridiculous name - "errorNew"

Comment: Yes..I go in my method when I do "go to declaration"

Comment: Check your syntax compliance level; I don't think it's actually 1.6.

Comment: Are you using an old java version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variable-arity method:

```
public void errorNew(final int a, final String key, final Object... params);
```

and this is a fixed-arity method:

```
public void errorNew(final int a, final String key, final Object[] params);
```

A variable-arity method is applicable if the number of actual arguments is equal or greater to `n - 1`, where `n` is the number of parameters declared by the method. A fixed-arity method is only applicable if the number of arguments is exactly equal to the number of declared parameters ([see the specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html))

So the difference is not at the bytecode level, but at the compiler stage: when the compiler has to resolve the method signature, the algorithm changes as I described above, depending on the declaration being a fixed- or variable-arity one. That's why the compiler doesn't complain when your `LoggerImpl` implements the `Logger` interface using a vararg parameter, but can't find the method when you call it on an instance of the `Logger` interface (method signatures are resolved statically at compile-time, not dynamically at runtime, depending on the actual type of the object)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys...my bad...
Actually the problem was -

In my LoggerImpl class, I had method signature -

```
public void errorNew(final int a, final String key, final Object... params);
```

but in my Logger interface, I had method signature -

```
public void errorNew(final int a, final String key, final Object[] params);
```

This was causing problem. I changed interface method signate to match impl signate and it started working. But I still don't know the reason. I used to think that they both are equivalent. ***Please let me know if there is some good reason...***

Thanks for your time guys..

Comment: The reason is that you were compiling against the interface and you didn't satisfy it. The implementation satisfies the interface, and your call satisfies the implementation, but it doesn't satisfy the interface.